# How to enable “replace by method reference” refactoring (and Java 8 features) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, java-8

IntelliJ can refactor this:

```
class Foo {
    static void bar() {}
    static {
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Foo.bar();
            }
        }.run();
    }
}
```

into that:

```
class Foo {
    static void bar() {}
    static {
        ((Runnable) Foo::bar).run();
    }
}
```

Isn't it nicer? (thanks [Anna Kozlova](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/java-8-and-method-references-in-intellij-idea-12/)). Now that Android supports Java 8, how can I do that in Android Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do several things.

First you need to be using a JDK 1.8 (amazing, no?)

Second condition is to set your `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 23 in your *build.gradle* file.

Then you need to enable Java 8 features by adding in the `defaultConfig` of your *build.gradle* file

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

You also need to enable the Jack toolchain by adding the following lines to the same section of your *build.gradle* file:

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

Finally, you also need `buildToolsVersion` set to 24 and above for your project to build.

You can then enjoy the full Java 8 features and related refactoring suggestion in Android Studio.

You can read more about Java 8 features and Android in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html).